# Using a simple map-reduce to list all keys in a bucket vs. bucket.get_keys()?

Tags: python, database, nosql, mapreduce, riak

According to Riak's docs (using Python bindings), [get_keys()](http://basho.github.com/riak-python-client/bucket.html#riak.bucket.RiakBucket.get_keys) is extremely expensive and not suitable for production.  My question is whether a very simple map query is suitable.  For instance, using a map stage only with the function:

```
function(v) { return [v.key]; }
```

is this going to perform better than get_keys()?  why wouldn't Riak ship with this implementation instead of the current version of get_keys()? Is there a better way I should be listing keys for a bucket?

Comment: Hello, you can make some performance measures with `timeit` module. Compare the two options, and see which is the fastest one; then you'll be able to know if Riak developers did a better work than your simple solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_keys()` function calls `list_keys` in the back end and is considered to be an expensive operation because it performs a full scan of the key space. Depending on your Riak back end, this could also involve a full scan of the data as stored on disk (InnoStore springs to mind). The default storage back end (Bitcask) stores all of your keys in memory, so performance shouldn't be as much of a problem.

The other reason `list_keys` was considered expensive is because it was formerly a blocking operation as it involved what the Basho developers refer to as a 'fold' over all of the keys. `list_keys` now uses a snapshot of the bucket (instead of reading the live key space) and this makes it a lighter weight operation as well.

This is made easier with an upgrade to Riak 1.0. If you're using the LevelDB back end, you can enable secondary indexes on a bucket and use the `$key` index (automatically provided by Riak) to get you a list of all keys in a bucket.

As for why Riak doesn't ship with a better implementation of something like this: ask what the functionality is for. In an RDBMS, getting all primary keys of a table involves a full table scan. In Riak, getting all keys from a bucket requires scanning all data in every node and then shipping the key names back to the originating node, combining that data, and then sending it to the calling client. Because of Riak's distributed, unordered, state this operation is expensive no matter how you slice it. There are, as I outlined above, ways to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the eleveldb backend (which is implemented with [LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) library) your keys are stored in an sorted order, so you can do something like:

```
def get_bucket_keys(riak_client, bucket_name, start='0', stop='Z'):
    for record_key in riak_client.index(bucket_name, '$key', start, stop).run():
        yield record_key

for key in get_bucket_keys(riak.RiakClient(), 'mybucket'):
    print key
```

With eleveldb riak scans all the nodes for only the range specified. So, if you populate your buckets in a way that you can control key ranges, list bucket keys can be very performatic.

The trade off is that you can't specify a LIMIT for the number of keys processed on each node. That is why you NEED to control the keys for the buckets you need keys listing.